# Deploying issues on Google App Engine With PHP

Tags: php, android, google-app-engine

"Getting current resource limits" as the message on logs.

How to fix this issue. I am trying past 4 hours, no improvement. Can anybody help me..

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine>appcfg.py update
>   E:\Andro+\AppEngine\TamilNewsHD\
>
> 12:36 PM Application: application-id; version: 1
>
> 12:36 PM Host: appengine.google.com
>
> 12:36 PM Starting update of app: application-id, version: 1
>
> 12:36 PM **Getting current resource limits**.
>
> Your browser has been opened to visit:
>
> If your browser is on a different machine then exit and re-run this
>   application with the command-line parameter

Comment: The log suggests that deployment passed the "Getting current resource limits" stage. Looks like it's waiting for authentication (which happens in a separate browser window - check your browser windows). Once authentication is completed the deployment should continue.

Comment: Login happens. But after that it opens with localhost script.. no changes happened on console.

Comment: Now its login and also deploying... but when i run https://<app id>.appspot.com/. It returns old code.. also i see in Google Cloud Platform/Activity, recent deployment changes are showing. But its not reflected on repository source code. Still old source code..

Comment: Thanks @DanCornilescu. Your inital help really turned my learning on GAE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes Finally i solved. Google may be taken few hours to allow me to deploy on GAE.

When i tired on next day. Deployment worked seamlessly. And also few issues like where the source get updated are taken few more hours to get understand. Anyhow i figured out how to deploy and run.

Now i am able to check deployment updates on 
**Google Colud Platform -> Appengine -> Versions**

Lots of progress has been made on today itself. Hope more i will learn about GAE using PHP in coming days.